# Python for loop based on criteria in one column return result in another column

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have an excel spreadsheet with a column called "Description" that I would like to itereate through. In this column are items that I use as criteria to categorize each item. For example, if the description column says "Interest on Investment" I would like the code to see that in the description column and return "Investment Income" in another column called "Category." I have tried this and can not seem to get it to work. You can see below that I have tried this different ways and I think that I am missing something simple such as classifying a string even though I have attempted this as well. If there are any questions please let me know or if more info is needed as I am just learning.

```
import pandas as pd

GLDetail = pd.read_excel("GL_DetailFY19.xlsx")

GLDetail["Category"] = ["Interest Income" if desc == "Income on Investment" else cat
                        for desc, cat in zip(GLDetail["Description"], GLDetail["Category"])]

GLDetail.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Gregg.Sawdy\Desktop\newxlrd\Test.xlsx', index = False)

print(GLDetail)
```

This is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Gregg.Sawdy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Category'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Gregg.Sawdy\Desktop\GLCatogories.py", line 6, in 
for desc, cat in zip(GLDetail["Description"], GLDetail["Category"])]
File "C:\Users\Gregg.Sawdy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in **getitem**
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "C:\Users\Gregg.Sawdy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Category'

> > > 

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `return "Investment Income" in another column called "Category."`  are you just trying to *return* that string from your function, or are you trying to modify the dataframe entry?  Or are you actually trying to modify the excel file?

Comment: Can we get examples of what you have before, and what you want after in a dataframe/table format?

Comment: What I am doing is creating a new column called "Category" and inserting a string called "Interest Income" in that column based on the criteria mentioned. I am then exporting the result into a new excel workbook. I have this code already and it's working.

Comment: Well, I got it to work. Thanks for the help, I thought that second example you gave me automatically created a new column, but it doesn't. Once I added the filed to the spreadsheet, it worked.

Comment: >"Once I added the filed to the spreadsheet, it worked.". Be careful! You haven't actually solved the problem, you've found a workaround. I strongly recommend you read through a pandas tutorial so that you understand _why_ this workaround works and how to do this correctly in the future. Good luck :)

Comment: Yes, I have been going through videos learining. The problem I was running into is that the way we created the column is the same as others are explaining. There is something I am missing and I will find out what it is. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you're using the equality operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`.

What you want is this:

```
for _, row in GLDetail.iterrows():
    if row["Description"] == "Income on Investment":
        row["Category"] = "Interest Income"
```

Notice that I made a couple other changes to your code as well, to make it cleaner. I changed `ind` to `_`, which means "this variable is unimportant and will not be used". Second, I got rid of the line `GLDetail.loc[ind, "Category"];`, which does nothing. Third, I got rid of the `else: pass`. I also corrected the spelling on "income".

Although a more python method would be to use a list comprehension. In this case:

```
GLDetail["Category"] = ["Interest Income" if desc == "Income on Investment" else cat
                        for desc, cat in zip(GLDetail["Description"], GLDetail["Category"])]
```

Comment: Ok, I am getting an error. I have updated the code above and also attached the error message. Am I supposed to install another package?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to read the error message before asking for help. In your case, it's `KeyError: 'Category'`. This is happening because `GLDetail` has no field `Category`. In your question, you should specify that you're trying to _create a new field_ called `Category`. You should also specify what the default value of the category field should be, because you've only specified what it should be if the description is "Income on Investment".

Comment: I did read it, I just didn't understand it. Like I stated in my original comment, I am just learning. Thank you for the help though friend, I really appreciate it.

Comment: In your second example, the "GLDetail["Category"]" prior to the "=" sign is actually creating a new field. When I leave after the "=" blank and run the module, it shows a new column(field) called "Category" that is blank, the problem is after the "=" sign is not executing and inserting the text. Unless I am misunderstanding the difference between field and column. I know a field is in a table and a column is in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry if my tone came off as rude; I didn't mean to be flippant, I meant read through it and google parts of it to try to understand what it means. I don't think there's a clear-cut answer to your question, because it's not clear what outcome you're trying to achieve. The best solution would be for you to just play around with pandas DataFrames and try to get an intuitive understanding of them, and maybe read through a tutorial (like [this](https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-pandas-tutorial-complete-introduction-for-beginners/) one).